# Adding observableHashMap through fxml

Tags: java, javafx, collections, fxml

Looking for the syntax to add an `observableHashMap` with key->value pairs directly in fxml. The hashmap im looking to record is this one:

```
Map<String, int[][]> rules = new HashMap<>();

rules.put("34Life", new int[][] { { 3, 4 }, { 3, 4 } });
rules.put("Amoeba", new int[][] { { 1, 3, 5, 8 }, { 3, 5, 7 } });
rules.put("Assimilation", new int[][] { { 4, 5, 6, 7 }, { 3, 4, 5 } });
```

etc

Comment: It's possible to do it, but apparently not with `int[][]`. If you switched to a custom `Rule` class, it would be easier.

Comment: You could directly create an `ObservableMap<String, List<List<Integer>>>` in FXML, but I don't see a way to do this with arrays. Mixing collections and arrays is not that good an idea anyway (it plays very badly with generics) and as @RAnders00 already points out, it's usually much better to define specific classes for your use case anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import com.mycompany.myapp.ParentWithMap?>
<?import com.mycompany.myapp.Rule?>
<ParentWithMap xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
    <fx:define>
        <Rule fx:id="firstRule" someData="I am first"/>
        <Rule fx:id="secondRule" someData="This will be second"/>
        <Rule fx:id="thirdRule" someData="And this is the third"/>
    </fx:define>
    <rules firstRule="$firstRule" secondRule="$secondRule" thirdRule="$thirdRule"/>
</ParentWithMap>
```

For this example, I created the following classes:

```
package com.mycompany.myapp;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableMap;
import javafx.scene.Parent;

public class ParentWithMap extends Parent {

    private ObservableMap<String, Rule> rules = FXCollections.observableHashMap();

    public ObservableMap<String, Rule> getRules() {
        return rules;
    }
}
```

```
package com.mycompany.myapp;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

public class Rule {

    StringProperty someData = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "someData");

    public String getSomeData() { return someData.get(); }
    public StringProperty someDataProperty() { return someData; }
    public void setSomeData(String someData) { this.someData.set(someData); }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Rule{");
        sb.append("someData=").append(getSomeData());
        sb.append('}');
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

```
package com.mycompany.myapp;

import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Sample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ParentWithMap parent = FXMLLoader.load(Sample.class.getResource("thefxml.fxml"));

        System.out.println(parent.getRules());
    }
}
```